# Attraction/repulsion forces between two magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, ferromagnetism

If I have two identical magnets of equal strengths producing equal repulsive forces between them, and if I replace one of the magnets with a stronger magnet (everything else remaining the same), how would the forces on both of them change, i.e. will they exert equal repulsive force on each other or not? Why?

Also, does the size or strength of the magnet affect this conclusion? In other words, replacing one of the magnets with a significantly larger or stronger magnet will produce uneven/unequal forces on both the magnets?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion “If two bodies exert forces on each other, these forces have the same magnitude but opposite directions.”

Answer (score 0):

A note may be allowed that points to a side effect.

A permanent magnet is a magnet because the magnetic dipoles of its subatomic particles have, in sum, an alignment that manifests itself as a macroscopic magnetic field. However, this alignment is far from the ideal state where the dipoles are all aligned in parallel. An external magnetic field, however, acts on the dipoles of the magnet and causes a strengthening or weakening of the magnetic field of the permanent magnet, depending on the same-pole or opposite-pole alignment of the two fields to each other.